# "Носок" или "носков"?

Tags: орфоэпия, морфология

Как правильно употребить тут множественное число?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Когда речь идет о парных предметах или предметах, состоящиз из нескольких частей, сокращение будут: *чулок, рожек, ботинок*. Но - *носков*. Это слово-исключение, хотя сейчас некоторые словари допускают оба варианта.

Answer (score 3):

Про чулки-носки есть запоминалочка: чем короче - тем длиннее. Носки короче, чем чулки. А слово в родительном множественного длиннее: носков, но чулок.

Comment: Об этом написано в учебнике 5 класса за 2000 какой-то ранний год. Там даже картинка была.

Answer (score 1):

Верный ответ: правильно - "носк**ов**".

Answer (score 0):

Носков, но чулок. Всё правильно.